# How to prevent config class from getting freed, when APP in background

Tags: android

I made an Android APP, which has an config structure, which contains data,and services I need throughout all activities.

I now face the issue, that if my APP is in the background for a while, my APP crash, because my config structure has been deleted.

In my config structure, I also have data, I can not easily recreate at runtime.

So in my first Activity, I create the config structure.

```
FreightWeightConfig config = new FreightWeightConfig(getApplicationContext()); // make sure our config is up and running
```

And the start of my config class looks like

```
public FreightWeightConfig(Context appContext) {
        instance = this;
        mApplicationContext = appContext;
        tcBlue.setCallingContext(appContext);
        tcBlueConfig = Config.getInstance(); // to make sure it is available straight away
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        ....
}
```

I have a second function in the config structure, which allows me to get the instance of my config class, which I need to get access to functions and interfaces in config and services.

```
public static synchronized FreightWeightConfig getInstance () {
        //if (FreightWeightConfig.instance == null) {
        //    FreightWeightConfig.instance = new FreightWeightConfig(getApplication().getApplicationContext());
        //}

        if (FreightWeightConfig.instance == null){
            FirebaseCrash.logcat(Log.ERROR, LOG_TAG, "Fatal Error : FreightWeightConfig.getInstance()==null. Try restarting the APP");
            FirebaseCrash.logcat(Log.ERROR, LOG_TAG, "Fatal Error : Killing ourself, as we have no chance to go on");
            //System.exit(0); // we are in a bad state
            // Toast.makeText(mApplicationContext, "Fatal Error : FreightWeightConfig.getInstance()==null. Try restarting the APP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

    return FreightWeightConfig.instance;
}
```

In every Activity, I created a variable that hold a copy the instance. This is simply, because I thought it tells the system, I still need this class, do not kill it. Which does not seem to work.

I first thought, whenever I find my config class to be dead, I can recreate it. But it is not a simple task, as I need the APP context and need to recreate my services in the background. Also I store selections made, while navigating my APP

Anyone has a good Idea, how to solve the unloading / deleting my config class?

Based on the suggestion I extended Application like this:

```
public class FreightWeightApp extends Application implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {

    private String LOG_TAG = "FreightWeightApp";
    private FreightWeightConfig config;

    public static int GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVIE_ABBORTED = 1001;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // We first check if the google services are present, if not, better abort!!
        int result = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        switch (result) {
            case SUCCESS:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Google Services available");
                break;
            case SERVICE_MISSING:
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Services missing, STOP");
                googleServiceNotUpToDateDialog(result);
                break;
            case SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Service update required");
                googleServiceNotUpToDateDialog(result);
                break;
            case SERVICE_DISABLED:
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Service disabled, STOP");
                googleServiceNotUpToDateDialog(result);
                break;
        }


        config = new FreightWeightConfig(getApplicationContext()); // make sure our config is up and running
    }

    private void googleServiceNotUpToDateDialog(int result) {
        // Try to ask the user to update or finish off
//        GoogleApiAvailability gaa = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
//        Dialog dialog = gaa.getErrorDialog(this, result, GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVIE_ABBORTED, this);    //<==== Can not call this, as I have no Activity Context
//        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        // Now I should abbort the APP, or we will crash.
    }
}
```

But now I have issues with verifying the GoogleService.

```
Dialog dialog = gaa.getErrorDialog(this, result, GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVIE_ABBORTED, this);
```

as I have no Activity Context.

Comment: Persist the state when the activity is paused and read the state when the activity resumes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own implementation of [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), then initialize your config object in the [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) method(in this case the getInstance() method could also initialize the object).

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FreightWeightConfig config = FreightWeightConfig.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

Declare your implementation in your app's module manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                         
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="your.package">                                            

    <application
        android:name="your.package.MyApplication"                                                              
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"                                     
        android:label="@string/app_name"                                       
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        ...            

    </application>                                                             

</manifest>
```

Now you can use your config instance in the activities just like you do, calling getInstance(); the Application onCreate will do the load work. But there is no way to "unload the resources before the app process gets killed/cached", you just have to understand how Android components' lifecycle works.

Comment: I like that idea, but before I can create my Config, I have to check if my GoogleService is up to date. Otherwise I get a crash. I use Google API in my Config, for example FireBase database.

Up to now, I did a call to 
getErrorDialog(Activity, int, int, DialogInterface.OnCancelListener);

As I have no Activity Context, I am a bit stuck again.

Comment: 1- remove the DialogInterface implementation from the Application class; 2- Remove all Google code from the Application onCreate method; 3- Put your Google code into your config class;  4- Initialize you config in the onCreate method as a Singleton. 5- Implement the DialogInterface in your activities and a callback of your config; 6- Call your config from your activity like this: FreightWeightConfing.genInstance().isPlayServicesOk(this), where this is your activity implementation of a callback your config is going to call when Play Service logic is done.

Comment: If I do like you say, I am back to my original problem.
If I do step 4, and my is a while in the background, the OS tend to kill and free my config.
That's why I did the new approach with the Application class.

My config needs to access Google (Firebase) code, right on creation.

Comment: I have a bit of luck. The functions I use early in my config, are already present in old PlayServices. Thus I could move my testing and Dialog Functions around similar to what "Diego dos Santos" suggested.